# Customize spring:form to render different value and tag content

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, taglib, spring-form

I have the following jsp:

```
<form:select path="terminalStatus">
     <form:options items="${allStatuses}"/>
</form:select>
```

it renders like this:

```
<select id="terminalStatus" name="terminalStatus">
     <option value="ACTIVE" selected="selected">ACTIVE</option>
     <option value="INACTIVE">INACTIVE</option>
</select>
```

I want that it renders a bit different. like this:

```
<select id="terminalStatus" name="terminalStatus">
     <option value="ACTIVE" selected="selected">label_1</option>
     <option value="INACTIVE">label_2</option>
</select>
```

Actually `allstatuses` is the set of enum values of `TerminalStatus`:

```
public enum TerminalStatus {
    ACTIVE("label_1"), INACTIVE("label_2");
    String label;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    private TerminalStatus(String label) {
        this.label = label;

    }
}
```

Does spring form allow to customize my jsp to get desired result ?

Answer (score 1):

`form:options` tag have special attribute for this (`itemLabel`):

```
<form:select path="terminalStatus">
    <form:options items="${allStatuses}" itemLabel="label"/>
</form:select>
```